# Error in locating and reading specific .env file, in django project

Tags: django, python-3.x, environment-variables

In my project, I just added new security methods, separating the .env from the project into another folder and adopting the use of new processes. To do this, I followed the ***python-dotenv lib documentation***, which I use in my app.

But even following the suggestion I can not find all the parameters, since I end up having the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty
```

**My settings:**

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
env_path = Path('/home/user/configs') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=str(env_path))
```

How can I resolve this problem from the specific path?

**Note**: I use in my project, python 3.4.5 and django 1.9.4, but I do not believe that the problem is caused by the old versions adopted in the project.

Another important detail is that the ***.env*** file is correct, because when I use it in the same folder where I find the file ***settings.py*** it works without problems!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using this approach and from past few months I'm following a very good developer and he also writes about a python dependency "python-decouple" and you will going to get it in detail at this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/26/package-of-the-week-python-decouple.html) 
I think this will definitely going to solve your problem.

Python-decouple github repo : [here](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I'm testing a new branch. Could you explain how I can find .env in another folder?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your point what you want to achieve here.

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not clear, I'm asking what would be the method with the python-decouple lib to find the .env file, for example in the linux opt folder?

Comment: you can make a .env file in your project directory where manage.py file exist and use it simply with the example I share above

Comment: The main purpose is precisely not to leave it inside the project folder, but rather in another location. So you would not have to insert the file every time you upgrade the project.

Comment: python-decouple helps you to secure your critical information and allow you to access them faster, as people push to websites like GitHub, its not good approach to share your important information so you can make a .env file in your project directory and put that file in .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

You can add the folder containing .env to the path. Here's how I did it:

```
load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "project", ".env"))
```

Answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62588097/9597908).