# How to import environment variables to Django from local file

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I'm preparing for production on my first professional Django project, and I'm having issues with environment variables to secure the the application. So far I've managed to create a local file to store all variables on my pc...

**env_variables.py**

```
import os

db_user = os.environ.get('db_user')
db_password = os.environ.get('db_password')

# AWS DJANGO
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "access_key"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "secret_key"
export AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "bucket_name"

print(db_user)
print(db_password)
```

I've used the environment settings(windows) to create username and password. When I run the file they work. I'm using my AWS credentials to test this. I've been under the impression that Django can access this information no matter where it is on my local pc. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**settings.py**

```
...

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

...
```

I know that Django isn't accessing this file because I get 400 for all of my media files, but it works when I place the keys directly into the settings.py file. I believe I'm missing a few steps here. I've seen other python coders capable of doing this without having to use something like django-environ or other packages. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated because I'd like to do this for all of my projects.

**Edit**
My Procfile's gunicorn is `web: gunicorn project_name.wsgi`
I have not modified my wsgi file.

Comment: Running that file could not possibly work, as it is a mixture of Python and bash syntax and isn't valid in either.

Comment: your settings.py file is fine. You're env_variables.py file as @DanielRoseman says doesn't make sense. The question is how do you set your environment variables. Normally you would activate a virtualenv, and use a daemon to run gunicorn or uwsgi in that virtualenv with these specific environment variables set to the values you need. e.g. if you use systemd to start gunicorn, you pass it `Environment` settings in the `[Service]` section of the config file.

Comment: so you should expand your question with how you run Django (gunicorn/uwsgi) and how these are configured.

Comment: When I run 'python env_vars.py' in my terminal, it prints my username and password. Am I mixing disciplines by accident here?

Comment: Is it required to place all the secrets in a .py file? If not, you can use **[python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv)** to load environment variables from a .env file. With a simple script added to your manage.py and wsgi.py, you can get it working for django.

Comment: @mbhargav294 I'm much more used to using a .env file. I'll attempt the solution presented by dirkgroten and then try this. It looks like I've been going in the totally wrong direction here. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I has same issue in Python 3.5, later versions work fine. Described my workaround at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62588097/9597908.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) to configure your app.
Keep all your config values in a separate file, say **.env** - This should not be added to the repo.

**.env**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "access_key"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "secret_key"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "bucket_name"
```

Now in your Django **settings.py** load the env file and use the corresponding keys.

**settings.py**

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()
env.read_env(env.str('ENV_PATH', '/path/to/.env'))
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
```

Comment: How can this be extended to other files , say `local_utils.py` - I get an `Set the <variable_name> environment variable`. I can access it from the `settings.py` but not from (selfwritten) utils-function

Comment: It worked for me after removing white spaces before and after equals sign in `.env` file.